# How to share IAPs across an iPad and iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've seen this done before with apps that I use, but I was wondering how it would be possible to share IAPs between an iPhone and iPad application. More specifically, I want to make sure that users that make a purchase in one app, do not have to re-buy the same product in the other.

I've read in a few places where this could only be accomplished with a universal app, but I wanted to see if this was, in fact, the only way that it could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, in-app purchases are app-specific. But it's really pretty easy to go universal - try out some of the excellent tutorials. You obviously have the advantage of only having to maintain a single code base (though of course you could be disciplined and share some core code, but it usually lapses...).